# InvokeRepeating didn't work well with Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have met a problem about the function `InvokeRepeating()`, they didn't work in parallel. I use a for loop in `Update()` to go through an array of 100 float and compare the figures in `InvokeRepeating()` every 1 second. If the figure given is less than that one in `Update()`, it will be shown in console.

But eachtime I saw is 99 for the `InvokeRepeating()` in console. Here is part of my code

```
void Update () {
    foreach(int f in test){
      target = f;
      Debug.Log (target);
    }
}

void AccXFunction(int time, float x){
     InvokeRepeating ("AccXR", 0.2f, 0.8F);
}

void AccXR(){
    float tempAccX = float.Parse(
           GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AccX")
          .GetComponent<Text>()
          .text);
    accEvent.AddListener (accXAction);
    if (tempAccX < 99) {
        Debug.Log ("Hi, got it, the" + target);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Func0 " + tempAccX);
    }
}
```

And here is the results in console: Only 99 but not other numbers from 0 to 98.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity only uses a single thread. `Update` will run from 0 to 99 then once it finishes it will do the pending InvokeRepeating. See the page for [Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

> Normal coroutine updates are run after the Update function returns. A coroutine is a function that can suspend its execution (yield) until the given YieldInstruction finishes.

If you want to have them run "at the same time" you need to use classes from the `System.Threading` namespace. However if you are not on the "Unity thread" you can't touch anything that Unity controls and exposes to the UI, you will need to find a [unity specific threading library](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher) to get your code to run on the UI thread again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really thought that they are in different threads. But I have a new question now: If we have a big calculate in the Update(or we have many scripts and each takes a little time), that means the Update functions will 'block' the coroutine?  There are numbers of big projects in Unity, they should have a solution...

Comment: Yes, if you have a big slow calculation in Update it will slow down your program, you can use [the built in profiler in unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/unity-ui-profiling-tools) to see how much of a slowdown it is causing. Most of the time the way to fix it is figure out more efficient ways to do whatever it is you are trying to do.